# Do page/author in-text citations go at end of quote or end of sentence?

Tags: quotations, citation

I was just arguing with my sister about the placement of a citation after a quote if the quote was not at the end of a sentence.

I thought it would be like so:

> According to me,"the citations go after the quote" (Jon 52) if they are not at the end of a sentence.

My sister had her citations like so:

> According to my sister, "the citations go at the end of the sentence" if they are not at the end of the sentence (Jess 52).

**Which is correct? Are they both correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MLA or APA, then you are correct; the citation does not have to be at the end of a sentence. [Here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/03/) is a great explanation of the correct way to cite quotations in MLA, and [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/02/) is an example of how to cite thing in APA. [Columbia College](https://web.ccis.edu/~/media/Files/Academic%20Resources/Writing%20Center/mla_examples.pdf) has some great examples of propper MLA citations.